# How can I save AWS Textract output in a searchable PDF format?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, text-extraction

Anyone has managed to save AWS-Textract output into searchable pdf format? I have had a look into numerous pages with no luck. I am surprised that AWS does not give you that functionality to allow you to save it in PDF format and rather give you Block format or .csv format.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you figure out how to do it?